# Extending Backbone.Marionette Module With CoffeeScript, CommonJS

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript, marionette, commonjs

I'm trying to extend marionette's module class in coffeescript, using a commonJS pattern, so that I can require a general Module class to reuse across parts of my app. So far, no luck.

So far I've tried this:

```
module.exports = class SingleFeed extends Marionette.Module

    @addInitializer((options) =>
        console.log 'initialize'
    )
```

and this:

```
module.exports = Marionette.Module.extend(

    @addInitializer((options) =>
        console.log 'initialize'
    )

)
```

With the hope that I could reuse this code in my application like this:

```
HomeFeed = require '../modules/components/feeds/SingleFeed'
hf = new HomeFeed()

app.module('HomeFeed', 
     moduleClass: hf
).start(options)
```

Has anyone successfully done this with coffeescript? Or does anyone have any ideas that might help?

Here's the documentation I'm referencing: https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.application.module.md

Comment: The reason your attempts don't work aren't related to CoffeeScript: it's more like you're doing the right thing at the wrong time, as @dmytro-yarmak explains in his answer. To extend a CS class or marionette module you need to provide an extension object; instead, your passing it the result of calling a member function. Worse still, there's no instance yet (you're defining a class), so calling `@addInitializer` doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

The problem that `addInitializer` is method of module instance but when you extended you can't call it. But you can override empty default `initialize` where you can add your initializers and finalizers like that:

```
module.exports = Marionette.Module.extend(
  initialize: () ->
    console.log('initialize module')
    @addInitializer((options) =>
        console.log 'starting module'
    )

)
```

Comment: Also, if you were overriding a *non-empty* `initialize` method, you could do `ParentClass.prototype.initialize.call(this, arg1, arg2, ...)` inside the new initialize method.